# Yii Consolidate and optional string in Yii URL patterns

Tags: regex, yii, yii-url-manager

Is there a way to consolidate the following Yii URL patterns? How to say, that for example a part is optional.

```
  '<category:.+>-rezepte/mit-<ingredient:\w+>/<effort:\d+>/<difficulty:\w+>'    =>  'recipes/index',
  '<category:.+>-rezepte/mit-<ingredient:\w+>/<effort:\d+>'                     =>  'recipes/index',
  '<category:.+>-rezepte/mit-<ingredient:\w+>'                                  =>  'recipes/index',
  '<category:.+>-rezepte'                                                       =>  'recipes/index',


  'rezepte-mit-<ingredient:.+>/<category:\w+>/<effort:\d+>/<difficulty:\w+>'    =>  'recipes/index',
  'rezepte-mit-<ingredient:.+>/<category:\w+>/<effort:\d+>'                     =>  'recipes/index',
  'rezepte-mit-<ingredient:.+>/<category:\w+>'                                  =>  'recipes/index',
  'rezepte-mit-<ingredient:.+>'                                                 =>  'recipes/index',
```

Comment: try putting the optional part between parenthesis and end with a question mark, e.g. (</diffculty:\w+>)?

Comment: If i set the ()? i get a wrong url from Yii's createUrl(). Something like: category1-rezepte/mit-ingre1/60(/all)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [This forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/35616-yii-url-rules-optional-parameters/) You should be able to do something like:

```
array(
    'recipes/index',
    'pattern' => '<category:\w+>-rezepte(/mit-<ingredient:\w+>)?(/<effort:\d+>)?(/<difficulty:\w+>)?',
),
```